# Syntax causing Segmentation Fault?

Tags: c

I downloaded a text file, I want to read a line, chop the lead and trail whitespace, and write the updated (new) line into another file.  I'm sure there are more eloquent ways of doing, but I'm trying to do it this way:

```
char *make_dst( char *src, int beg, int end ) {
    char *dst = ( char * )malloc( MAXLEN * sizeof( char ));
    int i = 0;

    if( dst != NULL ) {
        while( beg <= end ) {
            /* this works fine */
            dst[i] = src[beg];
            i++;
            beg++;
            /* this causes the segmentation fault */
            dst[i] = src[i + beg];
            i++;
        }
    dst[i] = '\0';

    return dst;
}
```

I don't understand why the second manner of doing it causing the error?  Can anybody explain this for me?  I'm using lubuntu 14.04 - is it an operating system thing?  I thought it was fine to use "math" in that manner to reference different indexes in an array?

Comment: It's fine as long as you don't over-index the bounds of the array... You need to be aware that `i+beg` needs to be less than `end` (or I guess `MAXLEN` in your specific case)

Comment: What is MAXLEN?  Consider how quickly you will segfault if MAXLEN was 5.

Comment: try printing the value of `i` and `beg` before you get to the line where you get the fault

Comment: It would help if you posted two different code blocks. But if I'm reading this correctly, the second case has a `while` that checks `beg <= end` but never increments `beg`, hence an infinite loop.

Comment: How is src[] allocated?

Comment: you should check whether this is true `end - beg < MAXLEN`

Comment: better yet, as they both appear to be indices, `malloc(((end-beg)+1)*sizeof(char))` bytes and get rid of MAXLEN entirely.  Yes, there is an extra set of parens in this comment.

Comment: ...and a superfluous `* sizeof(char)`, which 1 by definition.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker: heh :).  I'm so used to typing malloc(n * sizeof(something)) that my OCD gene didn't even kick in on that one.

Answer (score 3):

```
while( beg <= end ) {
    dst[i] = src[beg];
    i++;
    beg++;
}
```

This is correct because you're advancing both `i` and `beg` and assuring that `beg <= end`.

```
while( beg <= end ) {
    dst[i] = src[i + beg];
    i++;
}
```

In this case, you have an infinite loop, because if `beg <= end` was true initially, it will always be true after N iterations since the value of `beg` is never modified.

To correct it, the condition must ensure that `i + beg <= end` (This is assuming you want [begin, end] ranges instead of [begin, end), which is not wrong, per se).

`[begin, end)` ranges have the advantage of allowing you to specify cardinality conveniently.
`[x, x + 10)` means you have a range of size `10`. The equivalent is `[x, x + 10 - 1]`.

You want the size of the range to be a simple `end - begin`, and you want to include the lower bound. `[begin, end]` means you need special handling for empty ranges, and it would incur a lot of noise (-1, +1, you know the kind).

Comment: but doesn't he increment `beg` within the loop body as well?

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant The code snippets he posted separated by comments are actually distinct pieces of code he permuted inside the loop. At least, that's what I believe because he said "the second manner of doing it".

Comment: @MohammadAliBaydoun Thanks! Yes - that is the error ... pretty rusty when it comes to C.  That's the error, I wasn't incrementing beg so it caused the infinite loop.  Some things are so obvious and just can't be seen :( Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

```
the following code will go the job

char *make_dst( char *src, int beg, int end )
{
    int i = 0;
    char *dst = malloc( MAXLEN);
    if( NULL == dst )
    { // then malloc failed
        perror( "malloc failed" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, malloc successful

    memset( dst, 0x00, MAXLEN );
    for( i=0, i<(end-beg+1); i++ )
    {
        dst[i] = src[beg++];
    } // end for

    return dst;
} // end function: make_dst
```